# Is it possible to have a property sensor detect a value higher or lower than a specific number?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

Right now I have a simple logic setup (image below) to make the armor points of my tank go down and disappear when it gets hit by 25 objects with the *bullet* property. When it gets hit by 7 objects with the *missile* property, the *armor* property drops to 4, another makes it drop to 1, then it drops to -2. it never equals 0 and it never disappears.
Is there a way to send a positive pulse to the *And* controller if the property equals or is lower than 0?
<sub>click image for full size</sub>
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like "Less than"?

[image]

A value less than 1 is either equal to or less than zero.

**EDIT:** the options for evaluating properties "Less Than" and "Greater Than" was added in blender 2.71. Previous versions don't have these options.

The easy solution would be to upgrade to 2.71, another option would be to use a python controller to do the test of the property value.

Comment: It's not in 2.71 for me, but [later versions have it](https://developer.blender.org/rB8c16f4c7d0b334b70ec3b01ac1d81d280e9759b1).

Comment: @gandalf3 I have 2.71 built from the source tarball available from download.blender.org - that is a snapshot that is meant to correspond to all builds of the 2.71 release. That is now two things that I have and people have said isn't in 2.71. The other is separate/combine XYZ material nodes. Note that that commit was 16 June and 2.71 was released on 26 June.

Comment: @sambler I saw the dates, but I'm guessing that they were added after git was reopened for development on the next version, but before 2.71 was released and were not backported (I think only bug fixes are allowed within a few weeks of release). I tested on the binary download from blender.org and those features are not there. Perhaps a mistake was made with the source download?

Comment: [I reported it as a bug](https://developer.blender.org/T41280) as it leaves doubt as to whether bugs are fixed or introduced during release.